# Can I manage bower versioning via git tags only?

Tags: bower

I can specify `version` in `bower.json`, but it's quite daunting and I often forget to update it in my packages and need to do a 2nd commit.

Is it possible for Bower to read git tags and read versions purely from that? (much like Composer does for PHP). I couldn't find any information whether the `version` property in `bower.json` is required or not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `version` property is not required and Bower will happily read your git tags if they're valid [semver](http://semver.org/).

Comment: this reply is full of meanings :) A lot of projects have their tags like 'v0.5.3+2', those are **NOT** valid semver and they **cannot** be used by bower!
So in your repository use valid semver, without 'v' or any prefix.
Golden answer Sindre